# Using API to work with AWS Quicksight

Tags: integration, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to figure out if there are any ways to integrate part of the AWS Quicksight service into our web application or site.

Are there any support for embedding parts of the service in an web application or site? Or are there any support for working with it through API? Are there any other services on AWS that can be integrated with Quicksight to make this possible?

The parts or features of Quicksight we are most looking to use with out web application is uploading dat and modifying them with formulas or functions and retrieving the result from this. Similar to what you can do in software like Excel.

Comment: this feature was just released recently -> https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-quickSight-adds-support-for-dashboard-embedding-and-APIs/

Comment: You can look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedding-dashboards.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aws quicksight supports single sign on. If you are using amazon conginito to authenticate the users, you can embed the dashboard in your website. for embedding dashboard to your site please follow the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052069/10871299

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer