# How to get/generate aws quicksight secure dashboard url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I want to embed Quicksight dashboard to an application. I have gone through the AWS quicksight documents, I did not get where I will find secure signed  dashboard url.

Answer (score 16):

In order to generate Quicksight secure dashboard url, follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Create a new Identity Pool. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=us-east-1 , click **‘Create new Identity Pool’**

Give an appropriate name.
Go to the **Authentication Provider**s section, select **Cognito.**
Give the User Pool ID(your User pool ID) and App Client ID (go to App Clients in userpool and copy id).
Click **‘Create Pool’**. Then click  **‘Allow’** to create roles of the identity pool in IAM.

**Step 2:** Assign Custom policy to the Identity Pool Role

Create a custom policy with the below JSON.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:RegisterUser",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** if you want to restrict the user to only one dashboard, replace the * with the **dashboard ARN** name in **quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl**,

then goto the roles in IAM.
select the IAM role of the Identity pool and assign custom policy to the role.

**Step 3:** Configuration for generating the temporary IAM(STS) user

Login to your application with the user credentials.
For creating temporary IAM user, we use Cognito credentials.
When user logs in, Cognito generates 3 token IDs - **IDToken, AccessToken, RefreshToken**. These tokens will be sent to your application server.

For creating a temporary IAM user, we use Cognito Access Token and credentials will  look like below.

```
 AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
       AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           IdentityPoolId:"Identity pool ID",
           Logins: {
               'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/UserPoolID': AccessToken
           }
       });
```

For generating temporary IAM credentials, we call sts.assume role method with the below parameters.

```
var params = {
           RoleArn: "Cognito Identity role arn",
           RoleSessionName: "Session name"
       };
sts.assumeRole(params, function (err, data) {
           if (err) console.log( err, err.stack); // an error occurred
           else {
               console.log(data);
})
```

You can add additional parameters like duration (in seconds) for the user.
Now, we will get the **AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey** and **Session Token** of the temporary user.

**Step 4:** Register the User in Quicksight

With the help of same Cognito credentials used in the **Step 3**, we will register the user in quicksight by using the **quicksight.registerUser** method with the below parameters

```
var params = {
                   AwsAccountId: “account id”,
                   Email: 'email',
                   IdentityType: 'IAM' ,
                   Namespace: 'default',
                   UserRole: ADMIN | AUTHOR | READER | RESTRICTED_AUTHOR | RESTRICTED_READER,
                   IamArn: 'Cognito Identity role arn',
                   SessionName: 'session name given in the assume role creation',
               };

quicksight.registerUser(params, function (err, data1) {
                   if (err) console.log("err register user”); // an error occurred
                   else {
                       // console.log("Register User1”);
                   }
               })
```

Now the user will be registered in quicksight.

**Step5:** Update AWS configuration with New credentials.

Below code shows how to configure the AWS.config() with new credentials generated **Step 3**.

```
AWS.config.update({

                   accessKeyId: AccessToken,
                   secretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey ,
                   sessionToken: SessionToken, 
                   "region": Region
                 });
```

**Step6:** Generate the EmbedURL for Dashboards:

By using the credentials generated in **Step 3**, we will call the **quicksight.getDashboardEmbedUrl** with the below parameters

```
var params = {
  AwsAccountId: "account ID",
  DashboardId: "dashboard Id",
  IdentityType: "IAM",
  ResetDisabled: true,
  SessionLifetimeInMinutes: between 15 to 600 minutes,
  UndoRedoDisabled: True | False
}

quicksight.getDashboardEmbedUrl(params,
  function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(data);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Now, we will get the embed url for the dashboard.

Call the **QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard** from front end with the help of the above generated url. 
The result will be the dashboard embedded in your application with filter controls.

Comment: Thats a great answer, very helpful. do you potentially have a sample github project link to see all of the various pieces tied together?

Comment: please find the below [Github](https://github.com/sivasumanth483/quicksight) link for sample project on quicksight

https://github.com/sivasumanth483/quicksight

Comment: @SivaSumanth This is great and very helpful for me! I checked your github link and found that the getQuickSightUrl function takes an idToken parameter. Can you please tell me where you get that token from? In your step no. 2, you have mentioned that 
" When user logs in, Cognito generates 3 token IDs - IDToken, AccessToken, RefreshToken. These tokens will be sent to your application server."
Where exactly are these tokens sent and where can I find further info on implementing this for the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

this link will give you what you need from aws cli https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/

this is the step 3 aws cli cmd to give you embeded URL ( i was able to excecute)

```
aws quicksight get-dashboard-embed-url --aws-account-id (your account ID) --dashboard-id (your dashgboard ID) --identity-type IAM
```

there are many other dependence to enable the embeded dashboard per aws dcouments. i have not able to successfully doen that. GL and let me know if you make it happen!