# What is the simplest way of using Quicksight Rest API in React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I want to make api calls to Quicksight API in my React application. After investigation I found `@aws-sdk/client-quicksight` library however I did not find information how to authenticate to Qucksight using this library. There are examples in official docs of calling api methods but nothing about authentication part.

Also I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773313/how-to-get-generate-aws-quicksight-secure-dashboard-url/54052069#54052069) where they used Cognito to authenticate. According to other information I saw people use lambda functions.

I never used any AWS tools before. So is it possible to make API calls to Quicksight in React without lambda functions or backed code to handle auth part? Maybe I can provide credential to `@aws-sdk/client-quicksight` and simply execute api calls? But what credentials needed and how to provide them is not clear from documentation.